# Combine @math and @size in dust.js

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I need to get size + 1 of an array.

I tried the following but I can't figure the right syntax :

```
{@@math key="{@@size key=\"UsedFields\"}" method="add" operand="1" /}
```

PS: this code runs on a MVC app, thus the double @

Answer (score 2):

A helper cannot take another helpoer's results as a parameter.

You will need to use the @provide helper:

https://github.com/rragan/dust-motes/tree/master/src/helpers/data/provide

```
{@provide}
  {@math key=len method="add" operand="1"/}
{:len}
  {@size key=UsedFields/}
{/provide}
```